# average with first name ends in "e" excel 2013

Tags: excel-2013

How can calculate average revenue with people whose first name ends in `e` in large excel file. I tired with this formula.
`=AVERAGEIFS(sample!A:A;sample!B:B;"e")`

Comment: Close. You want `=AVERAGEIFS(sample!A:A,sample!B:B,"*e")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B200,--(RIGHT(A1:A200,1)="e"))/SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT(A1:A200,1)="e"))
```

Note how I have limited the ranges to rows 1 to 100; you dont want to use full column reference with SUMPRODUCT or it will slow down your spreadsheet.

I hope this helps